# Creating Multiple Records from a SQL record and assigning unique parameters to each

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database which contains the following fields

```
+Contract #
+Starting Odometer
```

For each record, I want to track the behavior for a designated mileage per year for 3 years. For Instance, assume the driver for contract 1 is expected to travel 15,000 miles per year. Then I want to generate the following 3 records:

```
contract_number starting_odometer year beginning_miles end_miles

1               X                 1    X               X+15,000

1               X                 2    X+15,000        X+30,000

1               X                 3    X+30,000        X+45,000
```

I am aware that SQL is probably not the most efficient for this process but my boss wants this done in SQL so its not really up to me

Comment: have a database which contains the following fields? is that database or table or field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start with a numbers table and just join in from there.  Here is an example:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < 10
     )
select t.contract_number t.starting_odometer, n.n as year,
       (t.starting_odometer + (n.n - 1) * 15000) as beginning_miles,
       (t.starting_odometer + n.n * 15000) as end_miles
from table t join
     n
     on n.n <= t.ContractYears;
```

Comment: Okay this may be asking too much, this has been a huge help already, but say I wanted to divide each record according to a 12000 mile band for analysis. For example if our starting mileage was 41,000 miles so I am in the band 48,000. I drove 15,000 miles in the first year so I want that record to split into 7,000 miles driven in year one under the 48,000 mile band, and the remaining 8000 miles to be driven in the 60,000 mile band. Could I use the table created from your answer as a temp file and then do a similar join with 12,000 mile bands?

Comment: @ZacharyLuety . . . That sounds like a different question.  You should not ask new questions in comments; you can ask a new question.